# Deployment of react app with express server gives blank screen but the app works fine with serve -s build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am running the express server on localhost:8080. The API is working fine.
I have added a new folder called public in express server source and added the react project source in the folder.

I have added **homepage:"."** but no results. The application works fine with serve -s build from root of App but not with the express server!

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { V1_Router } from './v1';
import path from 'path';

export const Routes = Router();

Routes
    .use('/v1/', V1_Router)
    .get('/*', async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('../public/build/index.html'));
    });
```

[image]

I have checked the console no errors! All Javascript and CSS files are completely loaded just not running for some reason please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Change it in something like that

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**EDIT1**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: Hi bro, this is not the problem. My code is under a sub directory, As I mentioned that the Express server is working fine, I am able to access the both API & Application but the Application is blank.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, All the scripts are loaded in the Chrome Browser Network tab. Just the bundle Javascript is not running!

Comment: the <div id="root"></div> stays empty!!

Comment: did you add static folder `public` in your code?

Comment: I also added proxy "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"

Comment: check the image I added to the question